# How to get a value from the yesod settings.yml file

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using the yesod scaffold. I'm struggeling a bit with how to get a value from the settings.yml file,

The relevant part of the settings.yml file looks like this,

```
Default: &defaults
  host: "*4" # any IPv4 host
  port: 3000
  approot: "http://localhost:3000"
  admins: ["someEmail@gmail.com", "someOtherEmail@gmail.com"]
```

And then in my Foundation.hs file I have a method to check if the users email (using googleauth) matches a pre-specified email,

```
admins = ["someEmail@gmail.com", "someOtherEmail@gmail.com"]

isAdmin (Just (Entity _ user)) | elem (userIdent user) admins = Authorized
                               | otherwise                    = AuthenticationRequired
isAdmin Nothing = AuthenticationRequired
```

My goal is to replace the admins function with the one from the the settings.yml file because it seems more appropriate.

Any help on doing this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Okay, I've come as far as fetching the newly made "extra" with the following method,

```
admins = do
    madmins <- extraAdmins getExtra
    case madmins of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just admins -> return admins
```

But the GHC throws this at me,

```
Foundation.hs:161:28:
    Couldn't match expected type `Extra'
                with actual type `Handler Extra'
    In the first argument of `extraAdmins', namely `getExtra'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: madmins <- extraAdmins getExtra
    In the expression:
      do { madmins <- extraAdmins getExtra;
           case madmins of {
             Nothing -> return Nothing
             Just admins -> return admins } }
```

Is there a way to convert it from Handler Extra to Extra, or am I simply doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the Settings.hs file in the scaffolding, there's the definition of `Extra` and how to parse it:

```
data Extra = Extra
    { extraCopyright :: Text
    , extraAnalytics :: Maybe Text -- ^ Google Analytics
    } deriving Show

parseExtra :: DefaultEnv -> Object -> Parser Extra
parseExtra _ o = Extra
    <$> o .:  "copyright"
    <*> o .:? "analytics"
```

You can add the extra data you want to this structure and parse it there. From the rest of your app, you can access this value with `getExtra` (defined in Foundation.hs).

Comment: hmm, actually getting the value, I'm doing `madmins <- extraAdmins getExtra` in a do block, but getExtra returns `Handler Extra` and it just needs `Extra`, so it complains. Any ideas? :/

Comment: This is a more general issue about how to deal with monadic values. A simple solution would be `fmap extraAdmins getExtra`.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit confused about the types of `getExtra` and `extraAdmins`.

I'm guessing they're like this:

```
getExtra :: Handler Extra

extraAdmins :: Extra -> [Text] -- maybe?
```

If so, something like this should work:

```
isAdmin :: User -> Handler Bool
isAdmin u = do
  extra <- getExtra

  return $ userIdent u `elem` extraAdmins extra
```

Comment: Been trying a bit to toy with your suggestion, but haven't quite figured out what I'm doing wrong :/ If you've got time, I've made some small gists of what I'm doing: [Settings.hs](https://gist.github.com/4704948) and [Foundation.hs](https://gist.github.com/4704956) ..